TypeError: dart.global.Croppie is not a constructor
Flutter Run on Web Using https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper/example
TypeError: dart.global.Croppie is not a constructor
../packages/image_cropper_for_web/src/croppie/croppie_dart.dart 129:50               new
../packages/image_cropper_for_web/src/croppie/croppie_dart.dart 68:12                new
../packages/image_cropper_for_web/image_cropper_for_web.dart 128:21                  cropImage
../dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
../dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
../packages/image_cropper_for_web/image_cropper_for_web.dart 72:33                   cropImage
InkWell(
  child: Icon(Icons.crop,
      size: 16,
      color:
          Theme.of(context)
              .iconTheme
              .color),
  onTap: () async {
    var croped =
        await cropImage(
            mediaFileList![
                index]);
    if (croped != null) {
      mediaFileList![
              index] =
          XFile(
              croped.path);
    }
  },
),

Future<CroppedFile?> cropImage(XFile? pickedFile) async {
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      final croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
        sourcePath: pickedFile.path,
        compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.png,
        compressQuality: 100,
        uiSettings: [
          AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
            toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
            initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
            lockAspectRatio: false,
          ),
          IOSUiSettings(
            title: 'Cropper',
          ),
          WebUiSettings(
            context: context,
            presentStyle: CropperPresentStyle.dialog,
            // size: const CropperSize(
            //   width: 520,
            //   height: 520,
            // ),
          ),
        ],
      );
      return croppedFile;
    }
    return null;
  }


Add following codes inside tag in file web/index.html and stop and re-run again:


<head>
  ....
  <!-- Croppie -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.5/croppie.css" />
  <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/exif-js/2.3.0/exif.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.5/croppie.min.js"></script>
  ....
</head>



